# Transform predictions on link scale to response scale for truncated distributions

Tags: r, regression, glmmtmb, glmm

I noticed when trying to back-transform predictions for my zero-truncated negative binomial model on the link scale to the response scale, the values are not the same:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame("x" = rep(1:5, 2), "y" = as.integer(runif(10)*100+1), "cat" = rep(c("a", "b"), each= 5))
mod <- glmmTMB::glmmTMB(y ~ x + (1|cat), data = data, family = truncated_nbinom2("log"))

new_data <- data.frame("x" = 1:3, "cat" = NA)
predict(mod, newdata = new_data, type = "response", re.form = NA)
exp(predict(mod, newdata = new_data, type = "link", re.form = NA))
```

Output:

```
> predict(mod, newdata = new_data, type = "response", re.form = NA)
[1] 79.08138 65.49391 54.24264
> exp(predict(mod, newdata = new_data, type = "link", re.form = NA))
[1] 79.07609 65.48655 54.23242
```

Why are they not the same? I specified the link function to be "log", then "exp" should invert it? The reason I don't directly predict to the response scale is that I want to calculate confidence intervals for an effect plot. Therefore I wanted to calculate the lower and upper confidence iterval using `exp(fit +/- 2* se.fit)`.

*Edit 1:* This also happens when starting in a "fresh" environment:

[image]

*Edit 2:* This does not happen when using not truncated distributions, e.g. `family = "poisson"` or `family = nbinom2("log")`. But other truncated distributions, e.g. `family = truncated_compois("log")`, also do not work.

Comment: I can't replicate this I'm afraid. I get identical outputs from both lines of code.

Comment: Can you give me what your output is when you call `.Machine$double.eps`? This is the only reason I can think of. Investigating the object, I found the inverse link function here: `mod$modelInfo$family$linkinv` and it uses `.Machine$double.eps`.

Comment: I get `[1] 2.220446e-16`

Comment: Actually, I seem to sometimes get a discrepancy depending on the random seed set. Can you include `set.seed(1)` at the start of your script and update your question so that we can see if this is reproducible?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, the value is the same for me, so this does not seem to be the issue. I changed the code to a fixed seed! Although I would like to mention that sometimes the error is really small, but sometimes the values are almost 1 count higher, which is not so good.... (e.g. seed 222 is much worse)

Comment: Thanks Zoe. I'm now getting exactly the same results as you. I'll look into this

Comment: Do you have any update on this yet? If you think this is a bug, I could also open an issue on the glmmTMB github?